# Cannot import datafile using TecplotReader([ ])... os.path.join(data_path, filename) Not Working?

Tags: python, paraview

I would like to import a set of datafiles using `for` loop on ParaView.
I think `TecplotReader(FileNames=[full_path])` takes FileNames as 'String' type, and `full_path` should be a 'string type' indicating the datafiles in the folder.

`TecplotReader(FileNames=['C:\\Users\\xxx\\Data\\TestToImport\\1147.dat'])` is working without using `for` loop, but I don't know why `TecplotReader(FileNames=[full_path])` is not working.

This is my code to import a set of datafiles automatically using `for` loop

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
import os, csv

# Test data to import : C:\Users\xxx\Data\TestToImport

data_path = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Data\\TestToImport\\'
save_path = 'C:/Users/xxx/Data/UpperPSP_CCG/'

for filename in os.listdir(data_path):
    full_path = os.path.join(data_path, filename)
    save_full_path = os.path.join(save_path, filename)

    #### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
    paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

    # create a new 'Tecplot Reader'
    a1147dat = TecplotReader(FileNames=[full_path])

    ...
```

I just got this error

```
  File "<console>", line 1
    a1147dat = TecplotReader(FileNames=[full_path])
```

And since the data is not readable from `TecplotReader`, there's nothing that I can do anymore.

Comment: Please put the entire traceback in your question — what you have in it now doesn't specify what error is occurring.

Comment: @martineau Oh, I solved the problem! My code was not wrong, but I had to run a Python script in ParaView correctly. Thanks anyway!